# Probability of not picking a particular ball, $W1$, out of an urn on the 1st pick, and not picking $W2$ on the 2nd pick?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

3 balls are chosen from an urn (without replacement) containing 5 white and 8 red balls. The white balls are numbered (that is, they are distinct), and the red balls are not.

[image]

Find $P\{Y_{1}=0,Y_{2}=0\}$.

Here is what I did:

$P\{Y_{1}=0,Y_{2}=0\}=P(Y_{1}=0)P(Y_{2}=0|Y_{1}=0)$

It is clear that,

$P(Y_{1}=0)=12/13$

Using the law of total probability,

$P(Y_{2}=0|Y_{1}=0) = P(Y_{2}=0|Y_{1}=0\, \bigcap \, X_{1}=W_{2} )P(X_{1}=W_{2})  +  P(Y_{2}=0|Y_{1}=0\, \bigcap \, X_{1} \neq W_{2} )P( X_{1} \neq W_{2} )$

Where, $X_{1}=W_{2}$ is the event where the 1st ball picked was the White ball #2.
And, $X_{1} \neq W_{2}$ is the event where the 1st ball picked was not White ball #2.

So,

$P(Y_{2}=0|Y_{1}=0\, \bigcap \, X_{1}=W_{2} )=1$

$P(X_{1}=W_{2})= 1/13$

$P(Y_{2}=0|Y_{1}=0\, \bigcap \, X_{1} \neq W_{2} )=11/12$

$P( X_{1} \neq W_{2} ) = 12/13$

And,

$P(Y_{2}=0|Y_{1}=0)=1(1/13)+(11/12)(12/13)=12/13$

Leading to the answer,

$P\{Y_{1}=0,Y_{2}=0\}=P(Y_{1}=0)P(Y_{2}=0|Y_{1}=0)=(12/13)(12/13)=144/169 \approx 0.85$

However, the correct answer apparently is, $15/26$. I am not sure where I messed up. Maybe I need to account for the fact that three balls are chosen from the urn? (The 3rd chosen ball seems to be irrelvant for the problem at hand though). Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that white ball 1 is chosen is $\frac{3}{13}$, so $\Pr(Y_1=0)=\frac{10}{13}$.

**Given** that white ball 1 is not chosen, the probability that white ball 2 is chosen is $\frac{3}{12}$, so $\Pr(Y_2=0|Y_1=0)=\frac{9}{12}$.

Multiply.

Comment: Wait, are you saying $Y_{i}=1$ if the ith White ball is chosen in any of the picks? I interpreted the problem as $Y_{i}=1$ if the ith white ball is chosen on the ith pick. I solved the wrong problem lol. Your interpretation should be correct; that's why the textbook gives such a lower probability for the answer. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I think the wording is clear, it says $Y_i=1$ if the $i$-th white ball is chosen. The notation is not optimal, since we are accustomed to $X_i$ being connected with what happens on the $i$-th trial.